# how to use a custom directive everywhere by specifying it in app.module?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

i am using a directive to get the clickevent .

my directive is

```
  import { Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({
selector: '[clickOutside]'
 })
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
}

@Output()
public clickOutside = new EventEmitter<MouseEvent>();

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
public onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {

    if (!targetElement) {
        return;
    }

    const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
    if (!clickedInside) {
        this.clickOutside.emit(event);
    }
}
```

}

when i use it inside in inventry.module.ts (for inventry page)  it works fine,

in inventry.module.ts i just added into the declarations.

```
 @NgModule({
imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule, FormsModule, ToastModule, DropdownModule, DatepickerModule, PaginationModule],
declarations: [ClientPurchaseOrderComponent, ClientPurchaseOrderAddComponent,ClickOutsideDirective ],
exports: [ClientPurchaseOrderComponent, ClientPurchaseOrderAddComponent, RouterModule]
  })
```

it works fine, what i want is if i need to use this in every module. so what i am trying is in app.module.ts i added the directive instead of in each and every module, but it is not working, not even giving any error?

```
  @NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    InventoryModule,
    LoginModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),
    ToastModule.forRoot(),
    DropdownModule.forRoot(),
    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    PaginationModule.forRoot(),
    DatepickerModule.forRoot()
],
declarations: [AppComponent,ClickOutsideDirective],
providers: [AuthGuard, LoaderService, HttpBaseService, UIService, SettingService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
exports:[]

   })
```

how to globalize a directive in angular 2 without adding in every module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't be available everywhere by default, relying on global entities opposes the concept of modules.

This is what module exports are for, [as explained in the manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module). Commonly used items can be re-exported from a common module to be used in other modules:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective],
  exports: [ClickOutsideDirective, CommonModule, FormsModule]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

So instead of

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule],
  declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

it will be just

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [SharedModule],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: i can add a sahredmodule, and declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective], this should ther in every module where i want to use?

Comment: And `exports: [ClickOutsideDirective]`. Yes, as long as you import SharedModule in these modules.

Comment: Can't export directive ClickOutsideDirective from SharedModule as it was neither declared nor imported! getting this error

Comment: See the code above. It states that you need to have `declarations: [ClickOutsideDirective], exports: [ClickOutsideDirective, ...]`. This is exactly what the example from the guide explains.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how Modules work in Angular.

A module only has visibility on it's own declarations.

But `Services` can be used globally without needing to `provide` it in every module.

And you cannot declare a directive in more than one Module.
otherwise you're gonna find this error :

> BlahComponent/Directive is declared by tho modules.

So the best thing you could do is to create seperate module and export your component from it and import that module in every other module that needs that component .

```
@NgModule({
  exports :[ClickOutsideDirective]
})
export class ClickOutsideDirectiveModule{
}
```

And then in your other modules:

```
 @NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    InventoryModule,
  ....
ClickOutsideDirectiveModule

],
declarations: [AppComponent],
providers: [AuthGuard, LoaderService, HttpBaseService, UIService, SettingService],
bootstrap: [AppComponent],
exports:[]

   })
```

Comment: i am creating the directive only once, but ot use it in inventery page, i have       to put this directivename inside inventry.module.ts
    if i want to use the same directive in diffrent page i dont need to create directive, i have to go to that module and put directive name their also. instead of putting this name every where can i put it in 1 place(app.module) and use it?

Comment: see this line,declarations: [AppComponent,ClickOutsideDirective], currently i need to do this in everysingle module to make the directive in all pages. i dont want to do that

Comment: Dude, I'm saying you can't even do that , unless they module are not used with each other at all.And there is no other way

Comment: so here declarations: [AppComponent,ClickOutsideDirective], directive name is necessory?